# How do I determine what the interval, [0,x] is if I am solving for the anti-derivative?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

A woman was driving for 8 miles and her velocity increased to 70 mph. How long did it take for her to get to that velocity?

I was given a curved graph and from my understanding, the area under the curve is the distance traveled.

So, I set up my integral as: 8dt | (upper limit: x, lower limit: 0) = 70

8t, [0,x] --> 8x=70, x=70/8

I got my answer wrong and I'm not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your expressions. It seems to me that you integrate the distance (so area is distance multiplied by time) and you get velocity (distance **divided** by time). Can you show the plot as well?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Velocity is equal to distance over time. Therefore, time is equal to distance over velocity, i.e. $t=\frac{8}{70}\sec$